# How do I perform graph colouring in networkx with a given number of colours?

Tags: python, networkx, graph-coloring

I am trying to solve an exam timetabling problem using graph colouring from the networkx library. I've taken the source code for the DSatur and the colouring algorithm and I'm trying to modify it for my specific requirements. I've made a graph with the exams as the nodes and if any two exams have even one student in common, they have an edge between them. The algorithm colours the graph with the fewest colours possible, but I need at least 512 colours (since there are 512 exam slots) to be used. I tried using equitable colouring and that works pretty well, but I would prefer using the DSatur algorithm since it schedules the exams with the highest degrees first. I'm confused as to how I can set the number of colours to 512. The highest degree for the graph is 203, which means it shouldn't be a problem.

My code for the colouring and DSatur heuristic are as follows:

```
def coloring_algorithm(G):
if len(G) == 0:
    return {}
colors = {}
nodes = DSatur(G, colors) #DSatur gives order of nodes
for u in nodes:
    neighbour_colors = {colors[v] for v in G[u] if v in colors}
    for color in itertools.count():
        if color not in neighbour_colors:
            break
    colors[u] = color
return colors


def DSatur(G, colors): #ADD PRIORITY QUEUE HERE
distinct_colors = {v: set() for v in G}
for i in range(len(G)):
    if i == 0:
        node = max(G, key=G.degree)
        yield node
        for v in G[node]:
            distinct_colors[v].add(0)
    else:
        saturation = {
            v: len(c) for v, c in distinct_colors.items() if v not in colors
        }
        node = max(saturation, key=lambda v: (saturation[v], G.degree(v)))
        yield node
        color = colors[node]
        for v in G[node]:
            distinct_colors[v].add(color)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: what do you mean by “but I need at least 512 colours (since there are 512 exam slots) to be used”? I think in the DSatur algorithm, the num of color used is determined during the execution and can not be set manually.

Comment: I need the graph to be coloured with atleast 512 colours because each colour represents a timeslot that needs to be filled. Is there any other algorithm that achieves this (like equitable colouring) that also preserves the order of nodes being traversed as in DSatur?

Comment: @TonyGunk I only have a stupid solution that use can assign new types of color to some vertices after finishing the DSatur. Why do you think the order of traversing is important?

Comment: By traversing from the nodes with the highest nodes, whant property do you want your coloring preserve? Is there a metric that measures how good a coloring is? Or are you just want to find one of the possible coloring?

Comment: The highest degree nodes have the most students in common and are high traffic exams which require larger rooms, therefore I want to schedule those exams first. This colouring algorithm has to essentially solve a handful of hard constraints (just having no clashes will do for now). Once this is done it will form the initial solution on which I hope to apply simulated annealing to solve the remaining soft constraints and produce an optimal timetable. I just need one coloring which satisfies the all hard constraints and fills as many timeslots for the time being.

Comment: You said "The highest degree nodes have the most students in common and are high traffic exams", this is not True. Higher degree means "it's time will confict with more other exams", instead of meaning it takes more resources like room.

Comment: @TonyGunk According to your description, every color corresponds to a time slot, and perhaps there are some resource limitations for every color. For this purpose, I think the DSatur algorithm is not suitable. I think perhaps you need to start with coloring the node that take the most resources(compared with largest degree in DSatur), and then the next. Another possible way may starting from any initial coloring, find the color that the sum of resources used by this kind of nodes, and change some nodes to a brand new color(also increase the number of color used). (please use @ to reply to me)